# Tags of the week! May 13-May 19, 2019: Tools & Language — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: May 13-19, 2019
TAGS: [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)

At the start of this week [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) had 182 questions and [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) had 128. Let see how high we can get them by week's end.

At the end of the week, [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) had 207 questions and [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) had 181.

---

## Results

This may have been a slow week for questions, but it was outstanding for retagging.

Congrats to our winner of the week, Liquid, for giving us our only official contest question, one on [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)

But hello retagging!  So many that I have to apologize for prolonged home page flooding.  Some tags just never got properly applied in the past (or the tags didn't exist then or other tags were more prominent).  Whatever the case, we added 25 [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) tags and a whopping 53 [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tags (including Liquid's question).

---

**This is the last tag of the week promo that will feature top 40 tags under 200 questions.**  Why?  Because we did them all!  We might repeat some later or move on to other tags or take a break.  That will be up to whoever takes up the mantle.  Enjoy!

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's seventh:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

This contest is linked from [this Meta.SE post about topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327017/162102).  (Please update it for new challenges.)

For a list of all targeted tags and their progress, see https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1987/32946

Comment: I think we should give it a week off. Then continue with a broader list of tags. Focused retagging efforts has been a net-positive result for the site. As long as that effort has a high velocity we should keep doing it.

Comment: @linksassin I will support you in whatever you or someone else chooses to take on.   I do want to be careful about retagging.  As useful as it is, it does flood the site and some people really hate that.  I don't want to make anyone feel unwelcome or like the site is a chore.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I suggested the week off. Let's let the site breathe for a bit and see what happens. Thanks for doing a great job to get us that much closer to generalist.

Comment: @linksassin Wanna put this suggestion into an answer here? https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2015/tags-of-the-week-promo-stage-1-complete

Comment: done! I had intended to but hadn't got around to it yet. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- Liquid, [language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) [How can you make up a convincing dialect?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45223/how-can-you-make-up-a-convincing-dialect)